# Height 100% with all viewport

Tags: css, height

I would like to have my portfolio grid to take all the viewport height, with all navigator and resolutions. I tried several things like height 100% or 100vh, javascript too, but it doesn't work. 
I use a builder and a plugin for this portfolio, maybe it creates a conflicts?! I don't know...

If someone have a solution it will be perfect!

The page is there : http://espacederessourcement.fr/

Thanks,

Paulette

Comment: With all the viewport height, do you mean that you don't want to see scroll bar for your front page ? Please clear your question a bit.

Comment: height 100% and height 100vh won't work because you have a header taking up some of the screen. In javascript you will need subtract the height of the header from the height of the window and then apply the result to the height of your `#content` element.

Comment: Your plugin calculate the height dinamicaly with javascript. With Developer Tools you should find the css class "grid-portfolio", it change the height dinamicaly with your browser, and all children change the position left/top with it. Is not only a css problem. If the configuration of your plugin does not allow it, I think it's not possible in a simple way.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right Baro, the plugin calculate the height dynamically. I'll try to contact the plugin's support to see if I can change this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the calc function of CSS so you can calculate the full height without the header bar ( In the example i'm supposing the header bar is high 50px)

```
.portfolio-grid { height: calc(100vh - 50px) }
```